# Is there a way to implement covariant return types when using a vector of member functions in C++?

Tags: c++, inheritance, vector, stdvector, covariant-return-types

My base class will look something like (with constructors of course):

```
class gBase
{
public:
    // The user will implement a vector of a vector of functions that can be called as g[i][alpha](k)
    virtual vector<cdouble (gBase::*)(double)> operator[] (uint i) = 0;
};
```

and I want a possible implementation to look something like this:

```
class g : gBase
{
public:
    g() : g_funcs({{g_00, g_01}}) {}
    vector<cdouble (g::*)(double)>  operator[] (uint i)
    {
        return g_funcs[i];
    }
private:
    vector<vector<cdouble (g::*)(double)> > g_funcs;

    // define each function.
    cdouble g_00(double k)
    {
        return 5.0;
    }

    cdouble g_01(double k)
    {
        return 3.0;
    }
};
```

Where am I going wrong in defining g_funcs? I run into this:

```
return type is not identical to nor covariant with return type "std::__1::vector<cdouble (gBase::*)(double), std::__1::allocator<cdouble (gBase::*)(double)>>" of overridden virtual function "gBase::operator[]"
```

Comment: Don't use pointers to member function, a vector of pointer to member functions in `gBase` is *not* the same as a vector of pointers to `g` member functions. Please learn about [`std::function`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) for a simple way of solving your problem.

Comment: For one, vectors of different element types are unrelated, regardless of the relationship between the element types. Second, `g` inherits privately.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `std::vector<T>` and `std::vector<U>` are not covariant even if `T` and `U` are covariant.  With template types, each specialization is it's own unique type with no relation to the other besides the template name.

What you need is a vector of a common type, and you can get that using `std::function`.  If both functions return a `std::vector<std::function<double(double)>>` then the derived function will override the base one.  You could then populate the functions in the vector by using a lambda that captures `this` so it has the object to call the member function on.

If you can't do that another option would be to use a `std::vector<std::function<double(gbase const*, double)>>` and then you would need pass a pointer to the object you want to call the function on plus the parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to return a `std::vector<cdouble (gBase::*)(double)>`, because there is no relation between `std::vector<cdouble (gBase::*)(double)>` and `std::vector<cdouble (g::*)(double)>`

Note also that `g[i][alpha](k)` isn't going to work to call one of those functions, as you aren't passing a `g` (as a `gBase`) that will be `this`. You could instead

```
(g.*g[i][alpha])(k)
```

Or with C++17

```
std::invoke(g[i][alpha], g, k);
```

But it really sounds like you want to bundle up `this` with the functions in the vector. In that case you should have

```
class gBase
{
public:
    // The user will implement a vector of a vector of functions that can be called as g[i][alpha](k)
    virtual std::vector<std::function<double(double)> > operator[] (uint i) = 0;
};

class g : public gBase
{
public:
    g() : g_funcs({{[this](double k){ return g_00(k); }, [this](double k){ return g_01(k); }}}) {}
    std::vector<std::function<double(double)> > operator[] (uint i)
    {
        return g_funcs[i];
    }
private:
    std::vector<std::vector<std::function<double(double)> > > g_funcs;

    // define each function.
    cdouble g_00(double k)
    {
        return 5.0;
    }

    cdouble g_01(double k)
    {
        return 3.0;
    }
};
```